# Analysis Services Excel KPI not appearing

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, ssas

I have an analysis services database with an excel front end.

At one point I had the KPI coming though to excel 2007 but now I have no option to select them. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Are certain columns not showing up entirely or are the columns present, but their drop downs not showing up?

Comment: They are not showing up at all

Comment: It turned out to be because I wasn't using the xlsx format.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already figured it out, did you make sure to re-process your KPI section or try re-deploying/processing again? If you are trying to access them through an Excel pivot table they should be there so if those two suggestions don't work try recreating your OLAP connection in XLS 2007.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be because I wasn't using the xlsx format